# Linq to Entity Connection Timeout, two Linq queries works differently

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities

I have just spent two days trying to solve the timeout problem in my application and recently made simple NUnitTets example to narrow down the problem which I can't explain.

Below are two test methods FindStatLinq and `FindStatMethod`, the `FindStatLinq` contains Linq to Entity and FindStatMethod contains a method to the same Linq to Entity query.

The magic starts when `FindStatLinq` takes `2 seconds` to execute but `FindStatMethod` fails with `EF Core execution timeout` and it fails after about 60 seconds.

Any idea what is going on here and where is the problem?

```
     DatabaseContext _db;

        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddDatabase("data source=xxx.xxx.x.xxxx;initial catalog=xxxx;user id=xx;password=xxxxx;connection timeout=600");
            serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
            _db = serviceProvider.GetService<DatabaseContext>();
        }

  public List<Log> Find(int userId, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, int page, int pageSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
        {
            var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
            return _db.Logs
                .Where(w => w.UserId == userId && w.DateStamp.Date >= startDate && w.DateStamp.Date <= endDate)
                .OrderByDescending(o=>o.DateStamp)
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(pageSize)
                .ToList();
        }

         //Takes 2 seconds
         [Test]
        public void FindStatLinq()
        {
            var startDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
            var endDateTime = DateTime.Today;


            int page =1 ;
            int pageSize=1000;
            var skip = (page - 1) * pageSize;
            var userId = 7841;


            var find = await _db.Logs
                .Where(w => w.UserId == userId && w.DateStamp.Date >= startDateTime && w.DateStamp.Date <= endDateTime)
                .OrderByDescending(o => o.DateStamp)
                .Skip(skip)
                .Take(pageSize)
                .ToList();

            Assert.Pass();
        }

         //Fails with timeout
        [Test]
        public void FindStatMethod()
        {
            var startDateTime = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-7);
            var endDateTime = DateTime.Today;

            int page =1 ;
            int pageSize=1000;
            var userId = 7841;


            var find = Find(userId, startDateTime, endDateTime, page, pageSize);

            Assert.Pass();
        }
```

---

An update, this is some kind of compiler error and I have opened an issue on EF core github  at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/20145

Comment: Nvm. ;) Wrong method you said is timing out...
I find it wierd, that you aren't "ToList" on the Find, what does "Find" do in this context.. ?

Comment: Functions are same. Why there will be different? I think it could be cache at DB. Try calling `FindStatLinq` first and then `FindStatMethod`. Or may be you can use `AsNoTracking()` with both queries.

Comment: @MKR The order of methods in which they run as test does not make any difference and AsNoTracking() doesn't help.

Comment: @MortenBork It is taken from our prod context and if is it asynchronous or synchronous doesn't't makes any difference.

Comment: No, this is not an async problem, I will update my question and make them sync methods.

Comment: @Tomas, I somehow manage to skip the fact you had included the Find method above the code... Sorry!
Can we see the DatabaseContext class? 

Entityframework normally has the "base" class called DbContext, 
Or is this just a standard named entityframework context? did you extend it?
Can I also ask you to Assert that your result in step one, contains an actual result?

Comment: @Tomas You could also try to run FindStatMethod twice, in two different tests, to validate it isn't the context causing the issue, if it is somehow disposed or invalidated after the first successful query?

Comment: @MortenBork I have found where is the problem but can't explain it. The problem is in startDate parameter name in the Find method. If I rename that parameter to lets say startDateTest everything works fast without time out. It seems some kind of fo compilation problem. I have posted on EF Core github.

Comment: That probably means that Sql Server has stored a suboptimal query plan for the old parameter names. If you clear Sql Server's plan cache both queries will perform equally. It's probably not related to EF.

Comment: @GertArnold Why SQL Server do that? I never heard about such an issue and this is extremely difficult to debug.

Comment: Then let this be the first time you hear about query plans and parameter sniffing.

Comment: @GertArnold But signature(SQL) is the same? How did it make "bad" execution plan using the same signature(SQL)? Could it be that first time I have passed wrongly formatted DateTime parameters and it made an execution plan which later used?